# Laravel Query Builder orWhere returns false result

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder, laravel-5.1

I need a query that counts the conversations that are not seen yet.
It works fine but when I also want to check if there are any conversations with the `from_id` it returns a wrong result.

```
Conversation::where('to_id', $this->id)->whereExists(function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('messages')
        ->where('seen', 0)
        ->whereRaw('messages.conversation_id = conversations.id');
})->count();
```

Result: 0

```
Conversation::where('from_id', $this->id)->whereExists(function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('messages')
        ->where('seen', 0)
        ->whereRaw('messages.conversation_id = conversations.id');
})->count();
```

Result: 0

```
Conversation::where('to_id', $this->id)->orWhere('from_id', $this->id)->whereExists(function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('messages')
        ->where('seen', 0)
        ->whereRaw('messages.conversation_id = conversations.id');
})->count();
```

Result 1

So I could run them both and add the result but there has to be a better solution.

**Update:**
I forgot the logic part of the `orWhere`statement.
The query is true when the left part is true or the right part. So when the to_id is equal to the id the whole query is true.

I solved it by putting the or statement in a function:

```
Conversation::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('to_id', $this->id)
        ->orWhere('from_id', $this->id);
})->whereExists(function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('messages')
        ->where('seen', 0)
        ->whereRaw('messages.conversation_id = conversations.id');
})->count();
```